# Profiling a Corda Application

Tags: corda

I am trying to run some instrumentation / profiling against a CorDapp - for this question the sample cordapp here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example.git version release-3.

However, when I try to attach VisualVM to the running PID as per `jvm runtime` from the corda shell, I get errors like the following:

(From the Profile tab of VisualVM)

`Mon Jun 11 15:17:36 BST 2018>>> Profiler Agent: JNI OnLoad Initializing...
Profiler Agent: JNI OnLoad Initialized successfully
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 18)
Profiler Agent: Established connection with the tool
Profiler Agent: Local accelerated session
Profiler Agent Error: Exception when handling command from client:
java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed`

or (From the Sampler tab)

`CPU sampling:
Not available. Cannot access threads in target application. Check the logfile for details (use Help | About | Logfile).`

The logfile gives me this helpful error:

`WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.profiler.NetBeansProfiler]: IDEAppStatusHandler - error: {)}
*** Profiler error (Mon Jun 11 15:17:59 BST 2018): exception while trying to get response from the target JVM:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
INFO [com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler.cpu.ThreadInfoProvider]: mxbeans.getThreadMXBean() returns null for Application [id: localhost-10884, pid: 10884, host: localhost]`

I've tried this both on MacOS and Ubuntu and I get the same issue - so I don't think it's a Java installation issue.

Any pointers !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualVM uses Java serialisation. Corda bans Java serialisation for security reasons.

See https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/internal/NodeStartup.kt#L204:

```
open protected fun banJavaSerialisation(conf: NodeConfiguration) {
    SerialFilter.install(if (conf.notary?.bftSMaRt != null) ::bftSMaRtSerialFilter else ::defaultSerialFilter)
}
```

Comment: Unsurprisingly you were once again correct @Joel - by disabling this part of the node startup meant that VisualVM could attach to the node and profile.